# ImportError: cannot import name 'gTTS' from 'gtts'

Tags: django, gtts

I want to use the gtts library over my django project so i also installed django-gtts.

The command "from gtts import gTTS" runs fine when I run it in a virtual environment in an empty folder, but the moment i install Django or django-gtts it starts giving me the error

`ImportError: cannot import name 'gTTS' from 'gtts' (/Users/amay/Desktop/untitled folder 2/tts/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gtts/__init__.py)`

```
asgiref==3.4.1
certifi==2021.10.8
charset-normalizer==2.0.10
click==8.0.3
Django==4.0.1
Django-Gtts==0.4
gTTS==2.2.3
idna==3.3
requests==2.27.1
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
urllib3==1.26.8
```

These are all the Dependencies in my Project and i am Running it on my Mac OS System.

What can be the possible error? **Is the gTTS module conflicting with some other dependency?**

Answer (score 1):

Would you like to try this code?

```
from gtts.tts import gTTS
```